# Deserialize JSON using specific properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize JSON without declaring every property in C#.  Here is a cut-down extract of the JSON:

```
{
    "resourceType": "export",
    "type": "search",
    "total": 50,
    "timestamp": "2020-08-02T18:26:06.747+00:00",
    "entry": [
        {
            "url": "test.com/123",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Slot",
                "id": [
                    "123"
                ],
                
                "schedule": {
                    "reference": {
                        "value": "testvalue"
                    }
                },
                "status": "free",
                "start": "2020-08-03T08:30+01:00",
                "end": "2020-08-03T09:00+01:00"
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

I want to get the values out of `entry` → `resource`, `id` and `start`.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: Only create the properties you need in your C# models.

Comment: "_without declaring every property in C#_", It sound like manual typing variable name. That's a simple copy past. either use online tools like [Json to C#](https://json2csharp.com/) , [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/), or a simple special past in visual studio directly.

Comment: For partial deserialization you will find a lot of example base on [Deserializing Partial JSON Fragments](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made very good experiences with [json2sharp](https://json2csharp.com/). You can enter your JSON data there and it will generate the classes you need to deserialize the JSON data for you.

```
public class Reference    
{
    public string value { get; set; } 
}

public class Schedule    
{
    public Reference reference { get; set; } 
}

public class Resource    
{
    public string resourceType { get; set; } 
    public List<string> id { get; set; } 
    public Schedule schedule { get; set; } 
    public string status { get; set; } 
    public string start { get; set; } 
    public string end { get; set; } 
}

public class Entry    
{
    public string url { get; set; } 
    public Resource resource { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    
{
    public string resourceType { get; set; } 
    public string type { get; set; } 
    public int total { get; set; } 
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; } 
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; } 
}
```

The next step is to choose a framework which will help you to deserialize. Something like [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

Comment: I have a property like this: "div": "<div xmlns=\"test\">" this is causing issues with conversion.

Comment: What problems? Can you post me the exception if any is thrown? Have you ensured you have a valid json format?

Comment: It looks like the extra "" case issues on json2sharp. But maybe it will be fine if i just use that property?

Comment: If you post the whole code, including this property, I can try to help you further. Having "div": "<div xmlns=\"test\">" in your JSON is perfectly valid according to the JSON format.

Comment: It was just json2sharp that was complaining code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you don't deserialize the lot (even if it's minimally populated) since you have to do the inner classes anyway.

Here is how you could bypass some of the classes (1) by digging into the `JObjects`

**Given**

```
public class Reference  
{
   public string value { get; set; } 
}

public class Schedule   
{
   public Reference reference { get; set; } 
}

public class Resource  
{
   public string resourceType { get; set; } 
   public List<string> id { get; set; } 
   public Schedule schedule { get; set; } 
   public string status { get; set; } 
   public string start { get; set; } 
   public string end { get; set; } 
}

public class Entry
{
   public string url { get; set; } 
   public Resource resource { get; set; } 
}
```

You could call

```
var results = JObject.Parse(input)["entry"]
                     .Select(x => x.ToObject<Entry>());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data without declaring classes, you can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JToken, JObject, etc.).  You can use the [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method with a [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression to get what you are looking for in a couple of lines.  Note that `..` is the recursive descent operator.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
List<string> ids = obj.SelectToken("..resource.id").ToObject<List<string>>();
DateTimeOffset start = obj.SelectToken("..resource.start").ToObject<DateTimeOffset>();
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jhBzl4

If it turns out there are actually multiple entries and you want to get the `id` and `start` values for all of them, you can use a query like this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var items = obj["entry"]
    .Children<JObject>()
    .Select(o => new 
    {
        ids = o.SelectToken("resource.id").ToObject<List<string>>(),
        start = o.SelectToken("resource.start").ToObject<DateTimeOffset>()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qe8NB7